# Telegraf + MQTT + influxdb: Modifying input of mqtt

Tags: mqtt, influxdb, telegraf

Let us assume I have various MQTT clients who send data within some topic, for instance for temperature sensors tele/temp/%devicename%/SENSOR in a JSON Format, such as

```
{"Time":"2020-03-24T20:17:04","DS18S20":{"Temperature":22.8},"TempUnit":"C"}}
```

My basic telegraf.conf looks as following

```
# Influxdb Output
[[outputs.influxdb]]
  database = "telegraf"

# sensors
[[inputs.mqtt_consumer]]
name_override = "sensor"
topics = ["tele/temp/+/SENSOR"]
data_format = "json"
```

My problem is now that I fail to do basic operations on that json data.

1. I do not want to save the host and the topic. How can I drop fields?
2. The topic contains the %devicename%. How can I add it as tag?
3. I cannot use  json_query, since the %devicename% is there and there is only one field.
4. How can I rename the field %devicename%_Temperature to "temperature"?

In general, I would like to have an easy way to keep only the measurement of a multitude of sensors in the following format

```
timestamp           |   temperature |    device 

2020-03-24T20:17:04 |         22.8  |   DS18S20
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I don't know telegraf, so I really can't answer your question....but in your sensors part of the conf file you have 'topics = ["tele/temp/+/SENSOR"]', but in your text you say '/tele/temp/%devicename%/SENSOR', which DOES NOT MATCH your conf file.  MQTT best practice is to never use a leading '/' slash in your topic field!  It adds an unnecessary level to your topic field and makes matching topics harder.

Comment: That was a typo, of course it is tele/temp/...

Comment: @varantir did you solve that problem? I'm trying to use Telegraf to store data into Influx and have similar problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to save the topic in InfluxDB set the following as part of your inputs_mqtt_consumer:

```
topic_tag=""
```

Adding the topic as a tag name can be done using processors.regex

```
[[processors.regex]]
[[processors.regex.tags]]
key = "topic"
pattern = ".*/(.*)/.*"
replacement = "${1}"
result_key = "devicename"
```

In this case the 2nd section of the topic would become the devicename.